# "debugging" scala annotation macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros

some of my scala annotation macro do not seem to get expanded, is there a way to inspect/log which expression gets passed to my annotation macro **at compile time**, because right now the code doesn't even compile...

```
def virtualize(tree: Tree): Tree = atPos(tree.pos) {
  tree match {
    case x =>
      println("LOG: "+tree) //will only be printed during runtime
      c.warning(tree.pos, "LOG: "+tree) //will only generate code for a warning 
      super.transform(tree)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to issue compiler warnings in annotation macros?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: tldr: c.info prints during compile time whereas c.warning does not. (Don't forget to include macro-paradise otherwise your annotation macro won't expand at all!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use idea then open terminal enter `sbt ~compile`will Time compilation
then you can see compilation info log  like follow in the terminal :

```
D:\git\scala-macro-example>sbt ~compile
[info] Loading project definition from D:\git\scala-macro-example\project
[info] Set current project to scala-macro-example (in build file:/D:/git/scala-macro-example/)
[info] Updating {file:/D:/git/scala-macro-example/}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to D:\git\scala-macro-example\module\macros\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] D:\git\scala-macro-example\module\macros\src\main\scala\macross\teach\WithHello.scala:16: type ClassWithFunc is not a member of package macross.annotat
ion
[error] class WithHelloImpl(val c: Context) extends macross.annotation.ClassWithFunc{
[error]
```

after

```
object ShowInfo {
  class Show extends StaticAnnotation {
    def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro ShowImpl.apply
  }

  class ShowImpl(val c: Context) {
    import c.universe._
    def showInfo(s: String) =
      c.info(c.enclosingPosition, s.split("\n").mkString("\n |---macro info---\n |", "\n |", ""), true)

    def apply(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
      val a: Seq[c.universe.Tree] = annottees.map(_.tree)
      showInfo(show(a.head))
      c.Expr[Any](Block(a.toList, Literal(Constant(()))))
    }
  }
}
```

useing like following:

```
object ShowInfoUsing {
  trait SuperTrait
  class SuperClass

    @ShowInfo.Show
  class ShowInfoUsing(val i: Int = 1) extends SuperClass with SuperTrait {
    def f = 1

    val a = 1
  }


}
```

you can see info logo in the terminal

```
[info]  |---macro info---
[info]  |class ShowInfoUsing extends SuperClass with SuperTrait {
[info]  |  <paramaccessor> val i: Int = _;
[info]  |  def <init>(i: Int = 1) = {
[info]  |    super.<init>();
[info]  |    ()
[info]  |  };
[info]  |  def f = 1;
[info]  |  val a = 1
[info]  |}
[info]     @ShowInfo.Show
[info]
```

Comment: Oh I see, so c.info does actually print during compile time whereas c.warning does not... Do you know what the "force" parameter is used for?

Comment: Actually my issue was that I didn't include the macro-paradise plugin, in that case the macro annotation does not even expand. Also the compiler does not issue a warning, however it does for sbt-console... Thanks anyways

Comment: `c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, "\nhello warning")`
i use the warning also will print warn 

`[warn] hello warning
 [warn]     @ShowInfo.Show`

and i also don't know the "force" parameter

Comment: [Macro annotations are only available with the macro paradise plugin (in Scala 2.10.x, 2.11.x and 2.12.x alike).](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html)
 
i think when you begin learning or use macro then 
look the [macro_doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/usecases.html) is useful

Comment: I know, I did it in another project I just forgot to add paradise and the scala compiler didn't give a warning about not expanding macros, using the sbt console it told me that I forgot macro paradise!